# How to pass connection options while using UnitOfWork. C# Entity Framework, dependency injection, Sqlite, unit of work

Tags: c#, entity-framework, dependency-injection

I'm new in C# and trying to figure out the usage of entity framework and dependency injection in .Net console apps. The requirements for the app is to get the connection string from `appsettings.json`. At the moment can't really figure out how should i pass connection options to `AVLdbContext`.

Here is my `AVLdbContext` class:

```
public class AVLdbContext : DbContext
{
    public AVLdbContext(DbContextOptions<AVLdbContext> options) : base(options){}
    public DbSet<Package> Packages { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Device> Devices { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating (ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Package>()
            .Property(p => p.Data)
            .IsRequired();
        modelBuilder.Entity<Device>()
            .Property(b => b.Imei)
            .IsRequired();
    }
}
```

And here is my `Main` class where I'm creating the services and the path for `AVLdbContext` and also trying to use `UnitOfWork`.

```
public class Program
{
    public static IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }

    static void Run()
    {
        var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
            .ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                Configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .SetBasePath(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory)
                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                    .Build();

                services.AddDbContext<AVLdbContext>(options =>
                    options.UseSqlite(Configuration["ConnectionStrings:DefaultConnection"]));

                services.AddSingleton<IUnitOfWork, UnitOfWork>();

            }).Build();

        host.Run();
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Run();

        var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(new AVLdbContext());
    }
}
```

Here's my `UnitOfWork` class.

```
   public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly AVLdbContext _context;

    public UnitOfWork(AVLdbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        Devices = new DeviceRepository(_context);
    }
    //.........
```

This is the error i'm getting while trying to use UnitOfWork. [image: Image of the error that the code line below is giving me]

Comment: Does your `AVLdbContext` also have a `constructor`?

Comment: Apparently you need to provide `options` (of type `DbContextOptions<AVLdbContext>`) to the `AVLdbContext` constructor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following extracts are from [Configuring a DbContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/configuring-dbcontext#using-dbcontext-with-dependency-injection).

> Application code (in ASP.NET Core):
>
> ```
> public class MyController
> {
>    private readonly BloggingContext _context;
>
>    public MyController(BloggingContext context)
>    {
>      _context = context;
>    }
>
>    ...
> }
> ```
>
> Application code (using ServiceProvider directly, less common):
>
> ```
> using (var context = serviceProvider.GetService<BloggingContext>())
> {
>  // do stuff
> }
>
> var options = serviceProvider.GetService<DbContextOptions<BloggingContext>>();
> ```

---

It's worth pointing out you don't need to use dependency injection in your app.

Again, from *Configuring a DbContext*.

```
var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<BloggingContext>();
optionsBuilder.UseSqlite("Data Source=blog.db");

using (var context = new BloggingContext(optionsBuilder.Options))
{
  // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, but there are requirements for my application that I need to use dependency injections and get connection string from a .json file